# How to get iter or mark of first and last visible line in GtkTextView widget?

Tags: gtk, gtk3

How can I get iter or mark of first and last visible line in GtkTextView widget? I cant find nothing on this topic.

Comment: what exact version of gtk you use? 2 or 3?

Comment: @AlexanderDmitriev GTK3

Comment: What do you mean by first visible line? The whole first line but not the second? How about when the width of the window changes and the first line wraps into the second?

Comment: An explanation on what you're trying to do would be very helpful here.